# Emacs hitting "too many files open"

Tags: files

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64bit`.

I encounter this problem when I opened too many files by a emacs function.
Error is signaled as a message and prevent me from opening more files.

I checked my `ulimit -a` which shows my `open files` limit is `1024`.
So I changed the files limit to `4096` by this [method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user).

After that, when I tried to open files more than `1024`, emacs quit instantly without signaling any error.

Any suggestion to this problem?

Comment: You're visiting >1024 files inside Emacs? Or do you mean you've caused this many open file-handles, due to accessing files without visiting them? Either way, *surely* your problem is that you are doing that in the first place, not that the limit is unreasonable?

Comment: That *is* a lot of open files. Maybe you should look for another way to do what you want?

Comment: Yes. Because because invoking a `start-process` make a `\dev\pts\number` file. I am trying to implement some multithread feature and test how many maximum `start-process` can be done. I wonder if file limit is the bottleneck.

Comment: Did you pay your GNU Emacs subscription fee on time? If not, your service is cut off after a certain number of files. You only get a certain number of free file visits. ;-)

Comment: Where do I have to pay my subscription? Is there a student discount?

Comment: This doesn't have to mean OP has opened 1000 files by hand. For example, a language server could be scanning all files in a project and could be eating up the file limit